# RBAC data permission

Tags: php, rbac

I have a question about RBAC system

In fact, I used this system in my website but I m going to apply it on data as well.

For instance, I have 2 groups named 'writeEconomyNews' and 'readEconomyNews'.

The user who is a member of 'writeEconomyNews' could send news through the 'addNews' action, but he can just add Economic news and the user who is a member of 'readEconomyNews' can just read the Economic news,besides, the member of 'writePoliticNews' is able to create politic news using the 'addNews' action.

To sum up, all the activities are done using the 'addNews' action, but different roles have different access about adding news.

Another example if I say is: members of the 'limit' group can just see the 20 latest news but the members of the 'admin' group could see all the news without limitation, as I said, permission is about for example the 'viewNews' action but different access for each group.

appreciate your consideration and waiting for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the RBAC structure following way.

[image]

Comment: May you explain more about the 'action with attributes'?is 'attributes' a field in 'permission' table in which the access is defined for example as json?

Comment: Mr.Khatri can you help me ?

Comment: yes, you can store collection of attributes - inside a permission table. (you can store list of attributes as binary data), and convert them back in collection of attributes when you get back from db, inside the code.  ex. permission table with column - attributes [datatype - binary]